# Access nested object values from local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

How to get nested object values from `localstorage`.

For example:

```
"metadata":"{
"receiver":{"name":"John"},
"document":{"type":"Sample doc"},
"issuer":{"signatory":"Admin2"}}",
"options": "{"title\":"Document Title","expireOn":"2022-03-12T00:00:00.000Z"}"
```

I need to store and get values of `name:john`, `type:sample`, `signatory:Admin`.

```
localStorage.setItem('metadata', JSON.stringify(data.metadata));
let metadata = localStorage.getItem('metadata');

console.log('metadata: ', JSON.parse(metadata));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did that metadata get mangled at some point? The first and last values are JSON strings themselves.

Comment: Can you please add the actual `data` object. It's not clear if `metadata` property is a JSON string or an object

Comment: metadata:
receiver:{name:John},
document:{"type:Sample doc},
issuer:{signatory:Admin2}},
options: {title:Document Title,expireOn:2022-03-12T00:00:00.000Z}

Comment: the data previouslyattached was sample data which i gave to postman..

Comment: here data is an object

Answer (score 0):

At first you should get the `localStorage` values and convert that to a JavaScript Object.

```
let metadata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('metadata'))
```

Then you can easily get or store data.

```
// Store 
metadata.receiver.name = 'example'

// Get
let name = metadata.receiver.name
```

You can do this way for other values also.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to save and get your JSON in localstorage.

Steps for getting nested object value.

- Step 1: Sample JSON

  var data = {"metadata":{"receiver":{"name":"John"},"document":{"type":"Sampledoc"},"issuer":{"signatory":"Admin2"}},"options":{"title":"DocumentTitle","expireOn":"2022-03-12T00:00: 00.000Z"}};
- Step 2: Converting JSON Object to a String format and Save in
  Localstorage `window.localStorage.setItem("metadata", JSON.stringify(data.metadata));`
- Step 3: Fetch Stringify JSON from localstorage and parse `var metadata = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("metadata"));`
- Step 4: Fetch nested Object value `console.log(metadata.receiver.name)`

Hope this answer is useful.

Comment: localStorage.setItem('metadata', JSON.stringify(data.metadata));

      let metadata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('metadata'));

      console.log(metadata.receiver.name);

Comment: when i tried to parse the above lines, following error occurs Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: sampleData = {
        receiver: {
          name: issuer,
        },
 
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        'https://test.swagger.print2block.in/docs/add-data',
        {      
          metadata: sampleData,
        },  {   headers: {
            'x-access-token': token,
          },
        },
      );
      console.log(data);
      // let metadata = data.metadata;
      localStorage.setItem('metadata', JSON.stringify(data.metadata));

      let metadata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('metadata'));

      console.log(metadata.receiver.name);